# Search among one result from each group in Solr

Tags: solr, fieldcollapsing

I have a Solr schema with a kind of versioning. IDs contain version number, so existing docs remain as new are indexed. Sample contents:

```
id = foo1
name = foo
version = 1
data = x

id = foo2
name = foo
version = 2
data = y

id = bar1
name = bar
version = 1
data = x
```

There are two distinct search scenarios: Search all versions or search only the latest. The first is trivial, but how do I implement a search in the `data` field for only the latest versions of each `name`? In the sample above I wish to search for "x" in latest, and expect to hit only "bar1".

I was hoping for a solution using http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing, but if I search for "x" with `group.field=name` Solr will group after search, giving me version 1 of the two names above. I would need it to work more like a filter query.

Comment: So are you saying that if you search for "x" you should get back a result with id="foo2"?

Comment: Nope, you should get bar1 but not foo1.

Comment: Found a new mailing list thread with an almost identical case: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201110.mbox/%3C4E9B3A70.2010901@ifactory.com%3E

Answer (score 2):

Dont think field collapsing would serve you the purpose.

I can think of couple of the options -

1. Generate an unique same id for the document, so that when you add the new current document the old one is overwritten and you have only one version of the document always.
2. If its possible to maintain an extra field for the documents which would indicate the status as CURRENT. Only the latest document would have the field value and you would need to reset the value for all the other version of the documents. This way you can easily filter out the latest documents by filter query and also search through all version with the filter query.

Comment: #1 would make my first search scenario impossible. Regarding #2, is there a good way to mark the old document as not CURRENT when adding a new one? I think I'd have to reindex it.

Comment: #2 handling needs to be done from the database (or your source side), and would surely need reindexing all the versions of the documents again.

Comment: OK. It can be plan B, while hoping for better options. An alternative is to index immediately to two cores, one that overwrites (your option #1). Docs can be large though, so I'd want it to be a single submit.